# Creating a dictionary with ParseObject as key in cloud code only gives [Object object]

Tags: dictionary, parse-platform

I am creating a dictionary something like this `[<ParseObject>, List<ParseObject>]` in java script in Parse.com. This dictionary is set in `response.success` for retrieval at client side. My problem is on client side I only receive 1 row in dictionary because Parse.com is not serialising the key. It is serialising values properly. In keys it only inserts `[Object object]` so every time save key-value pair in map is over-written.

here is my code

```
query.find({
    success: function(eventResults) {

        console.log("Got results from Event table");
        var speakersList = {};

        // we now will get complete event speaker table and process it in a loop
        // then make a dictionary
        var query = new Parse.Query("EventSpeaker");
        query.include("SpeakerId");
        query.include("EventId");
        query.find({
            success: function(eventSpeakerResults) {
                // now we have all event speaker table
                console.log("Got results from EventSpeaker table");

                for(var i = 0; i < eventResults.length; i++)
                {
                    var speakersInThisEvent = [];

                    // notice this idiot "id" here it ate my 1 hour :-/
                    var eventObjectId = eventResults[i].id;

                    console.log("EventId: " + eventObjectId);

                    for(var j = 0; j < eventSpeakerResults.length; j++) 
                    {
                        if(eventObjectId == eventSpeakerResults[j].get("EventId").id)
                        {
                            console.log("Found a match !!");
                            speakersInThisEvent.push(eventSpeakerResults[j].get("SpeakerId"));
                        }
                    }

                    // this logs prints perfectly
                    console.log(eventResults[i].get("Location"));
                    //eventResults[i].Location = eventResults[i].get("Location");
                    //speakersList[JSON.stringify(eventResults[i])] = speakersInThisEvent;
                    //this is what creating issues eventResult[i] is always same (Object object) 
                    speakersList[eventResults[i]] = speakersInThisEvent;
                }

                // to be called only once
                response.success(speakersList);
            },
            error: function() {
                response.error("EventSpeaker Querying failed");
            }

        });
    },
```

here in keys instead of getting distinct objects i get only `[Object object]`. I cannot use `JSON.stringify()` as its not stringifying pointer object inside it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you're trying to use a Parse.Object as an object key. JavaScript only supports strings and numbers as keys for objects.

What I'd do in this situation is use `eventResults[i].id` for the key in your `speakerList` object.

If you need to return a few different objects, like the array of speakers, and the array of objects for those keys to map back to, you can return them wrapped in another object in your response:

```
response.success({ 
    speakers : speakersList,
    events : eventResults
});
```

And you'll then have everything send down in the response.

Comment: ok I got the answer but, each event has a speaker list in my case how i can map event to corresponding speakerlist in the way you have wrapped object ?

Comment: The mapping is kind of already there. The speakerList maps an event object ID to your array of speakers at the event. Once you know the event, you can get its corresponding speakers using `speakersList[event.id]`